# Detecting non responsive websites with no RWD with python

Tags: python, responsive-design, web-crawler

Is there a way to **reliably** scrawl (python 2.7) a website and determine whether it is responsive and thus will adapt to mobile devices or not? I want to build a crawler who screens multiple websites and stores the ones which are non mobile friendly.

I've heard methods like
-Finding websites without a "viewport" in their DOM HTML code
-Looking through CSS media queries

Do you know a way to accurately detect non responsive websites? Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a web page doesn't have in its head a viewport meta tag then it's unlikely it will be responsive, ie you would look for

```
<head>
...
<meta name="viewport" content= SOMETHING>
...
</head>
```

Two cases you might want to consider that would fail the above test.

If a site uses device detection to route users to say a mobile or desktop site based on their device, then although the mobile or desktop sites may not be responsive, this wouldn't be obvious to an end user and their experience could be good.

Another case I can think of is a page that uses javascript to detect viewport size and uses the result to modify the page or the page's stylesheet.

On balance I think searching for a viewport meta tag would give good results, though don't expect it to be perfect.

I hope this helps!